# What is Tawhid in islam?

Tags: tawheed

What is Tawhid in islam according to quran and hadeed? Please explain it in detail. And what are the different types of Tawhid

Comment: It is a bit strange to call it tajweed and then speak of types that sounds a bit self-contradictory.

Comment: @Medi1Saif well I was just trying to fit in the standard of the website. It was not accepting my question till "in detail" so I wrote the next half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaam,
Tawhid is the oneness of God, in the sense that he is one and there is no god but he, as stated in the shahada. The three aspects are:
1: Tawhid-ul-Rububiyyah maintaining the unity of **Lordship** (there is only one creator and sustainer),
2:Tawhid-ul-Uluhiyyah maintaining the unity of **worship** (only He is to be worshipped).,
3Tawhid-ul-Asma’ wal-Sifat maintaining the unity of **Allah's name and attributes** (describing Allah the way He has described Himself, and the way His Messenger (peace be upon him) described Him; and naming Allah with the Names that He has named Himself with)
Hope that helps:)

Comment: Some where I heard about fear of Allah. So is this in Tawhid